# im trying to run a program that copy the text from one file to the other

Tags: c++, c, linux

im trying to write a program that gets two text files and copy`s the text from one file to the other.
the function seems to be working but it changes the file that I write in not in to a text file.

please help!!!!

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Hello World!\n"); 
    char* file1 = argv[1];
    char* file2 = argv[2];
    char buffer1[SIZE+1];
    //char buffer2[SIZE+1];
    int fd1, fd2;
    int run = 1;
    int run2;



    fd1 = open(file1, O_RDONLY);

    if(fd1 < 0){
        perror("after open ");   // checks if the file was open ok 
        exit(-1);   
    }

    fd2 = open(file2, O_RDWR );

        if(fd2 < 0){
        perror("after open ");   // checks if the file was open ok  
        exit(-1);
        }

    while(run != 0){
        run = read(fd1, buffer1, SIZE);     
        run2 = write(fd2, buffer1, SIZE);
        printf("run 2: %d", run2);
    }



    close(fd1);
    close(fd2);
    return 1;

}
```

Comment: Did you try perror after the write? What did it say?

Comment: [Here is a question very similar to yours.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333869/copying-data-from-one-text-file-to-another-in-c)

You may want to reconstruct your code.

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  There is a fast and simple method in C++ using the `rdbuf` structure, which isn't present in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because

```
 fd2 = open(file2, O_RDONLY);
```

Read only file -> fd2

Answer (score 0):

Your program doesn't handle the case where the quantity of data read is less than the buffer size:

```
while(run != 0){
    run = read(fd1, buffer1, SIZE);     
    run2 = write(fd2, buffer1, SIZE);
    printf("run 2: %d", run2);
}
```

If the amount read is less than SIZE, you will be writing garbage to the second file.

Why are you using low level file I/O?

This can be done using C language functions, at a high level:

```
FILE * input;
FILE * output;
input = fopen("input_file.bin", "rb");
output = fopen("output_file.bin", "wb");
while (!feof(input))
{
  int quantity = fread(&buffer1[0], SIZE, 1, input);
  int bytes_written = fwrite(&buffer1[0], quantity, 1, output);
}
```

In the above example, the number of bytes written is the number of bytes read.  If the quantity of bytes read is less than `SIZE`, it will write the quantiy of bytes read to the output file, no more, no less.